# MVC 3 - Set non-required field to required at the client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-validation

I'm building an MVC 3 application.

Can I set a non-required field to required in the client-side(using JavaScript / jQuery)?

I need it to be dynamically when things change in the page.

UPDATE: I viewed the source code of my page and saw the window.mvcClientValidationMetadata array which validation-rules are pushed into it. Can I use it for my needs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want on the client side.

You can hookup to the form submit event and in it check if the field has been filled or not and either submit the form or display an error message as needed.

Of course, if JavaScript is turned off or if the user knows enough this field may end up being not filled, so always check on the server side (in addition to `Model.IsValid`, you can add checks for fields that you have not specifically added the `RequiredAttribute` to).

Another alternative, if your validation logic is complex, is to override [`ModelMetadata`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelmetadata.aspx) to provide custom validation.

Comment: Why doing it if I can harness the MVC's build-in client-side validation API script?

Comment: @YairNevet - You just stated that the field is not required. I understand that to mean that your model will not have the `RequiredAttribute` on it. Of course, if you want to, add this attribute to the property on the model and you are good to go.

Comment: The field should be required only in some cases, not at the initialized state.

Comment: @YairNevet - Which is why you need custom logic. You can't add a `RequiredAttribute` that will sometimes apply and sometimes not.

Comment: This is why I need it at the client-side.

Comment: Which is still custom logic. You can add the `data-*` attributes that the validation plugins uses. But you need to add them conditionally (again, custom logic).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14917/discussion-between-yair-nevet-and-oded)

Answer (score 0):

You can set validation rule like this:

```
$('element').rules('add',{
    required: true
});
```

And remove it:

```
$('element').rules('remove', 'required');
```

Or you can add custom validation method that will require value conditionally. see this: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod

Comment: on which library 'rules' depends on? i'm getting "object has no method 'rules'".

Comment: jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

Comment: When creating mvc 3 and mvc 4 projects (don't know about earlier versions) there are these files already included: jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js and jquery.validate.js. Include it if it is not